# Как в symfony transport динамически создавать очереди?

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

Как сделать так чтобы каждый запрос создавал отдельную очередь? Сейчас у меня очередь прописана напрямую вот так: MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/%2f/meta
Мне нужно чтобы каждый запрос пользователя создавал отдельную очередь, и консумер немедленно приступал к ее обработке, а не накидывать все в одну очередь и последние запросы ждали когда обработаются более ранние?

Answer (score 0):

В Symfony и Symfony Messenger вы можете динамически создавать очереди для каждого запроса пользователя, используя параметры конфигурации и динамические имена транспорта. Это позволит вам избежать ожидания обработки запросов другими запросами и обеспечит отдельную очередь для каждого запроса. Вот как это можно сделать:

Давайте начнем с первого

Создайте фабрику для генерации динамических имен очередей. Например, вы можете создать класс QueueNameFactory:

```
// src/Service/QueueNameFactory.php

namespace App\Service;

class QueueNameFactory
{
    public function createQueueName(): string
    {
        // Генерируйте уникальное имя очереди на основе данных пользователя или запроса.
        return 'user_queue_' . uniqid();
    }
}
```

В конфигурации Symfony, определите этот сервис:

## config/services.yaml

services:
App\Service\QueueNameFactory: ~

Используйте фабрику для генерации имен очередей в месте, где вы отправляете сообщения в Messenger. Например:

```
// src/Controller/YourController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\QueueNameFactory;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class YourController extends AbstractController
{
    private $messageBus;
    private $queueNameFactory;

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $messageBus, QueueNameFactory $queueNameFactory)
    {
        $this->messageBus = $messageBus;
        $this->queueNameFactory = $queueNameFactory;
    }

    public function yourAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Генерируйте уникальное имя очереди для текущего запроса.
        $queueName = $this->queueNameFactory->createQueueName();

        // Отправьте сообщение в очередь с динамическим именем.
        $this->messageBus->dispatch(new YourMessage($request->getContent()), [
            'amqp' => ['queue_name' => $queueName],
        ]);

        // Верните ответ клиенту.
        return new Response('Сообщение отправлено в очередь: ' . $queueName);
    }
}
```

Обновите настройки вашего транспорта (в вашем файле .env или в .env.local), чтобы использовать динамические имена очередей:

MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/%2f/%s

Обратите внимание на %s в конце DSN, который будет заменен на имя очереди, созданное вами динамически в контроллере.